# How do i move referenced DLLs with debug/release in VSCode?

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-code, msbuild, csproj

### Set up

I converted a C# VS2015 console application project over to VSCode and im trying to add a DLL reference and move any referenced DLLs on build.

To start off, `Dotnet add package` didnt work, with the error `The project does not support adding package references through the add package command.` so i added the project manually to the `.csproj` file. The package i want to add is a local version, located at `./Lib/AutoItX`

```
Lib/
   └── AutoItX
        ├── AutoItX3_x64.dll
        ├── AutoItX3.Assembly.dll
        ├── AutoItX3.Assembly.xml
        └── AutoItX3.dll
```

additions to `.csprog`

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="AutoItX">
      <HintPath>.\Lib\AutoItX\AutoItX3.Assembly.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

The reference works, and if i manually move the DLL into the Debug folder, it finds it and all is well.

### Question

Is there a way to automate moving the DLL into the folder?

currently, after a fresh run, my debug folder looks as followed:

```
bin/
   └── x64
        └── Debug
            ├── AutoItX3.Assembly.dll
            ├── AutoItX3.Assembly.xml
            ├── Application.exe
            ├── Application.exe.config
            └── Application.pdb
```

i would like the `AutoItX3_x64.dll` included automatically on x64 builds, and if possible, the `AutoIt3.dll` included on x86 builds (its not currently set up for x86 builds, i just want to know how)

### Additional Information

my `launch.json`

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (console)",
            "type": "clr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "compile",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/Application/bin/x64/Debug/StartApplication.exe",
            "args": ["./Download/start.json"],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "console": "externalTerminal",
            "stopAtEntry": false
        },
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Attach",
            "type": "clr",
            "request": "attach",
            "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
        }
    ]
}
```

my `tasks.json`

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "compile",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "args": [
                // Ask msbuild to generate full paths for file names.
                "msbuild",
                "Application.sln",
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                "/property:Platform=x64"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "presentation": {
                // Reveal the output only if unrecognized errors occur.
                "reveal": "silent"
            },
            // Use the standard MS compiler pattern to detect errors, warnings and infos
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        }
    ]
}
```

`Application.sln`

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio 14
VisualStudioVersion = 14.0.25420.1
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Application", "Application\Application.csproj", "{E9AA3396-3EAD-47EE-9927-F20D87B34BF6}"
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
        Debug|x86 = Debug|x86
        Debug|x64 = Debug|x64
        Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
        Release|x86 = Release|x86
        Release|x64 = Release|x64
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {E9AA3396-3EAD-47EE-9927-F20D87B34BF6}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {E9AA3396-3EAD-47EE-9927-F20D87B34BF6}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {E9AA3396-3EAD-47EE-9927-F20D87B34BF6}.Debug|x86.ActiveCfg = Debug|x86
        {E9AA3396-3EAD-47EE-9927-F20D87B34BF6}.Debug|x86.Build.0 = Debug|x86
        {E9AA3396-3EAD-47EE-9927-F20D87B34BF6}.Debug|x64.ActiveCfg = Debug|x64
        {E9AA3396-3EAD-47EE-9927-F20D87B34BF6}.Debug|x64.Build.0 = Debug|x64
        {E9AA3396-3EAD-47EE-9927-F20D87B34BF6}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {E9AA3396-3EAD-47EE-9927-F20D87B34BF6}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {E9AA3396-3EAD-47EE-9927-F20D87B34BF6}.Release|x86.ActiveCfg = Release|x86
        {E9AA3396-3EAD-47EE-9927-F20D87B34BF6}.Release|x86.Build.0 = Release|x86
        {E9AA3396-3EAD-47EE-9927-F20D87B34BF6}.Release|x64.ActiveCfg = Release|x64
        {E9AA3396-3EAD-47EE-9927-F20D87B34BF6}.Release|x64.Build.0 = Release|x64
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

### What I know and what I've tried

[microsofts docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/web-deployment-in-the-enterprise/understanding-the-project-file) show that you can use a metatag `<DependentUpon>`, which i tried with no luck.
The docs also mention [conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-conditions?view=vs-2015) which are used else-ware in the `.csproj`, which make me think that once i have one configuration that works, i can make a condition to make it work for both platforms.
One more thing that seems like it could solve this specific issue is [tasks](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks), but this feels very brute-force-ish, and i wouldn't know how to parse the `.csproj` for all external, local DLLs to move.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[this post](https://andrewlock.net/including-linked-files-from-outside-the-project-directory-in-asp-net-core/) was really helpful in explaining how to link content.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="..\Shared\SharedSettings.json" Link="SharedSettings.json" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
</ItemGroup>
```

By using the conditionals from the [linked documentation in the question](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/web-deployment-in-the-enterprise/understanding-the-project-file), I was able to move the DLLsfor x86 and x64 respectively.

This was the final solution for the `.csproj`

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="AutoItX">
      <HintPath>$(ProjectDir)\Lib\AutoItX\AutoItX3.Assembly.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Content Include="$(ProjectDir)\Lib\AutoItX\AutoItX3_x64.dll" Condition="'$(Platform)' == 'x64'" Link="AutoItX3_x64.dll" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
    <Content Include="$(ProjectDir)\Lib\AutoItX\AutoItX3.dll" Condition="'$(Platform)' == 'x86'" Link="AutoItX3.dll" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
  </ItemGroup>
```